# Best way to store/process user-specific API key and secrets?

Tags: laravel, oauth, api-key

I'm designing an app that counts on accessing multiple API's that need the certain users credentials which are provided when a user allows access via OAuth. I'm new to designing programs like this and I'm trying to wrap my head around the easiest way to do this. Here is what I was thinking:

- During the Oauth process I specify the callback url (lets call it A)
- Create a POST route for url A that points to a function in the user controller
- That function then parses the JSON data with the API Key+Secret, hashes the data, and stores it in a column of the user table.

Would this be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

One thing I'll say is don't tie these directly to your users.  Sometimes users may want to authorize multiple accounts, and sometimes multiple users may authorize the same account.  Since you can only have one active refresh token per oauth account, these creds should be kept in a separate table and then linked with a many-to-many for flexibility